# MySQL trigger insert not working

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have a table called Incidents with a few columns with one called **user_name**. I want to set up a trigger that when a record is inserted into the table a trigger is fired that inserts the user's name into the **user_name** column. Here is the trigger that I created in phpMyAdmin - but when I add a record to the Incidents table the **user_name** is blank:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `incidents_user_bi`;CREATE DEFINER=`bb`@`localhost` 
TRIGGER `incidents_user_bi` BEFORE INSERT ON `Incidents` FOR EACH ROW set 
new.user_name = current_user()
```

I thought my logic was correct - am I missing something?

Comment: Triggers in MySQL cannot act on the tables which caused them to fire.  Is the `user_name` column in a table _other_ than the `Incidents` table?

Comment: No the user_name column is only in the Incidents table. I do have a separate table that has all of the user names. Is there another way to add the user name to the user_name column when a new record gets added to the table? I suppose that will be another post

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just insert `CURRENT_USER` with the original insert statement directly?

Comment: I'm inserting via php - i couldnt get it to work properly. I'll have to take look again

Comment: I don't think a trigger is going to work, but I am playing the devil's advocate and asking why can't this user information be part of the direct insert.

Comment: Make sure your trigger actually exists (e.g. that the user bb exists, and that you didn't execute something after this, as the query is missing a `;` and will give you an error if some code is following this. If you executed it in the phpmyadmin sql panel, it should be fine though). Then check the datatype for your column `user_name`. It might be too short or not a varchar.